# JSP form bean with Servlet action

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

File `Test.jsp` :

```
    <form action="servlet.action">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    </form>
```

File `person.java` :

```
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
```

File `TestServlets.java` :

```
    doPost() {
        ...
    }
```

How to make the form fields in jsp map to pojo and use in servlets?

Comment: There's no direct way to do that using plain Servlets and JSP. There are frameworks like Spring MVC or JSF that do this trasnparently for the programmer.

Comment: With plain Servlets and JSPs you can only put some attributes in the `request` or `session` (via servlet) and retrieve them in JSPs. There is no such thing as mapping. Have a look to JSF or use a framework (Spring, Wicket, ... there's plenty of them).

Comment: I know you specified a Servlet but if you could use a JSP instead, then you could use  <jsp:useBean id="person" class="test.Person" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="person" property="*" />  That is how we did it in the pre-framework days.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to go about this with `Servlet`s, which ruled before `Struts` and `Spring`:

### webapp/Test.jsp or WebContent/Test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="servlet.action">
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First"> <input
            type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last"> <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlets</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>TestServlets</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlets</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet.action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Test.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### TestServlets.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestServlets extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFname(req.getParameter("fname")); //Populate fields from request parameter
        person.setLname(req.getParameter("lname"));

    }
}
```

### Person.java

```
public class Person {

    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

}
```